# How does == comparison of 2 dictionaries work when the value is a mutable type like list (does order matter)?

Tags: python, python-3.8

When we use the `==` operator on 2 dictionaries, then it checks that each dictionary has the same key/values irrespective of order since dict is inherently unordered

However, for a value inside the dict, if it is a mutable type - example: list, then how does the `==` work in terms of order of elements in the list value?

Comment: Yes, order matters for ordered types. It's not about being mutable or immutable. Dict and set are mutable and conceptually unordered. List and tuple are ordered, so two instances are equal of they have the same elements in the same ordered.

Comment: If the values are different then they're different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, order matters for ordered types. It's not about being mutable or immutable. Dict and set are both mutable and **conceptually** unordered (even if dict happens to preserve insertion order).

List (and tuple) are ordered, so two lists are equal of they have the same elements in the same order.

If you have an ordered type (e.g. a list) as a value in a dict, then the dict items can be in any order, but the elements inside the list itself have to be in the same order, for two dicts to be considered equal.

E.g.

```
{'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]} == {'B':[3,4], 'A':[1,2]}
```

Dicts are conceptually unordered, and these two dicts describe the same contents (in a different order).

However:

```
{'A':[1,2]} != {'A':[2,1]}
```

Lists are ordered, so the two lists in the dictionaries are not equal; therefore the dictionaries are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

> since dict is inherently unordered

Note that they aren't since 3.7 (they are insertion ordered, like lists).

> how does the == work in terms of order of elements in the list value?

You compare element by element, in the given order. If any differs, then it is different.

> if the value is a mutable type

Being mutable or not is irrelevant, the same that applies to a tuple applies to a list.

Comment: It also depends what you mean by "ordered".

Comment: @PeterWood I think we can agree insertion order *is* an order :)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing mutability with being ordered or not. Sets are mutable but are unordered (order does not matter).

The answer to this question has nothing to do with `dict` implementation of `__eq__` (which `==` calls) since it is delegated to the values types' implementation of `__eq__`.

Simply put, if `v1 == v2` then `{'a': v1} == {'a': v2}`.

`[1, 2] != [2, 1]` so `{'a': [1, 2]} != {'a': [2, 1}`.

Similarly, `{1, 2} == {2, 1}` so `{'a': {1, 2}  == {'a': {2, 1}}`.

I didn't check the C implementation of `dict.__eq__` but it is probably equivalent to (maybe with some more fancy optimizations):

```
if len(d1) != len(d2):
    # dicts don't have same # of keys, can't be equal
    return False

for k1, v1 in d1.items():
    try:
        v2 = d2[k1]
    except KeyError:
        # d2 does not have a key that d1 has, can't be equal
        return False       

    # delegating the check to the value's type implementation of ==    
    if v1 != v2:
         # d1 and d2 have the same key but the value is different, can't be equal           
        return False      

# all keys and values in d1 and d2 are equal, so dicts are equal    
return True
```